# how many holomorphic functions satisfy a specific requirement

Tags: complex-analysis

hope you are all well and healthy in this difficult time. I wondered if you could help me with one question I couldn't manage, I think I was able to do the (i) but for the (ii) I really have no idea. Thank you in advance!

the question is the following:
In each of the following two cases is it possible to find a holomorphic function
on $D(0, 1) = \{z ∈ C : |z| < 1\}$ satisfying the condition

(i) $f(\frac{1}{n}) = (−1)^n
, n = 2, 3, . . . \infty.$

(ii)$ f(\frac{1}{n}) =\frac{ n}{(n+1) }, n = 2, 3, . . . \infty.$

If it is possible, in each case indicate how many functions satisfy the requirement. Explain your answer

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! At the moment your question is in danger of being closed because it looks like it may be missing context or details. There is a standard of saying a bit more where you are in the problem, so we can explain at a level that is approriate for you. You could expand you question by saying how you solved (i), and what is causing you trouble on (ii).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in $(i)$, you simply mean that $f(1/n) = -n$, then the answer is no, because there's no way to extend it to function continuous at 0, much less holomorphic.

In $(ii)$, you want a function satisfying $f(1/z) = z/(z+1)$. It's easy to see that $f(z) = (1/z)/(1/z + 1) = 1/(1+1/z) = z/(z+1)$ agrees with on specified points, and is holomorphic on $\{|z| < 1 \}$.

Comment: Hello! thank you for your time. We need to find how many functions for the (ii) satisfy the condition

Comment: Answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

(i) is not possible since a holomorphic function is continuous and you can't have a continuous function satisfying condition (i).

For (ii) I can think of one holomorphic function that is $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$
And this is the only one possible by the uniqueness property of holomorphic function .

Suppose I have two holomorphic functions on $D(0,1)$, $f $ and $g$ satisfying the property (ii) then $0$ is an accumulation point of the set on which the two functions are equal then we have $f=g $.

For reference have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) .